# PHP - how to sort using usort by order of priority

Tags: php

Hi all I have a xml object where I can get type based on index eg

```
(string)$this->xmlSimple->test[$i]->type
```

Type can be 2 values 'B', 'N' and B takes priority over N

Currently I sort my expected array like so:

```
$sortedArray = [];
$allowedTypes = ["B", "N"];
$count = $this->xmlSimple->test->count();

foreach ($allowedTypes as $type) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ((string)$this->xmlSimple->test[$i]->type == $type  {
            $sortedArray [] = $i;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can achieve the same using sort or usort, so that it is sorted by B first and ordered index by B first and then type N

Thanks

Comment: If types are `B` and `N` what does `P` have to do with it, Maveric?

Comment: that is a sort, you can't then use `usort` or `sort`,, with a custom sort either your custom sorting or your using a pre-built sort.

Comment: @Barkermn01 Apologies I mean instead of my sort. I am trying to explore the build in php functions instead

Comment: Well for a custom sort you need to use `uasort` however looking at your code it does not look like a sort at all but a filter, if it's a filter use `array_filter`

Comment: Maybe if you show us examples of the inputs and the required result, we woudl be able to understand the requirement better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP sort array by priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511018/php-sort-array-by-priority)